# Best way to get timestamp in Google AppMaker

Tags: javascript, timestamp, google-app-maker

What is the best way to get **timestamp** to save it on **appmaker datasource**? I have tried following method:

```
var timestamp = new Date();
var timestamp = getTimeStamp();
```

But still got error .. please help :)

Comment: what is the error you getting ?

Comment: If I put it on server script the error is -- > ReferenceError: "getTimeStamp" is not defined. at sendRating (server:8)

Comment: If I put it on client script the error is -->  
getTimeStamp is not defined
at setRating (client:6:16)
at RateToilet.Image5.onClick:4:3

Comment: use only `new Date();`. Don't use the other one and you won't get any error.

Comment: I am using normal Google Cloud Platform that save data in google Drive. Thanks the new Date() function is working. But the getHours(), getMonth() and getDate() function does not return correctly as my timezone. Could you please advise ..

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing, that you are trying to set `CreatedTimestamp` or `UpdatedTimestamp` field of your model in `onBeforeCreate` or `onBeforSave` [model event](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/events). If you are using Cloud SQL as your databackend then normally you would chose between [Date, Datetime and Timestamps SQL Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html). Timestamp SQL seems to be your best choice for this purposes. Anyway, regardless what databackend you use and what date type you choose in App Maker you can always initialize date using date:

```javascript
// onBeforeCreate server event handler
record.CreatedTimestamp = new Date();
```

If by some reason you want to store number of [milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now), you can try to pair field of type Number and `Date.now()`:

```javascript
// onBeforeCreate server event handler
record.NumberTimestamp = Date.now();
```

Comment: I am using normal Google Cloud Platform that save data in google Drive. Thanks the new Date() function is working. But the getHours(), getMonth() and getDate() function does not return correctly as my timezone. Could you please advise ..

Comment: You can try to play with Time Zone in app settings.